# Add the content of a variable whose name contains ::

Tags: javascript, filemaker

I am building a site using javascript.
My data comes from a FileMaker API.

My goal is to fill an array with the data retrieved from the FileMaker API.

Except that this data comes from a linked table in FileMaker, which appends :: to the name of the variable.

Here is the code I'm trying to do, but with :: it doesn't work. How can I go about including ::?

```
for(var i=0;i<allFEC.length;i++)
{
    programmesMovies.push({
        "isOnline_b":1,
        "_idWeb_c": allFEC[i].pro_FIP::_id_FEC
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `"_idWeb_c": allFEC[i].pro_FIP::_id_FEC` with `"_idWeb_c": allFEC[i]['pro_FIP::_id_FEC']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that has spaces or any such weird syntax you can access it using square brackets

```
for(var i=0;i<allFEC.length;i++)
{
    programmesMovies.push({
        "isOnline_b":1,
        "_idWeb_c": allFEC[i]["pro_FIP::_id_FEC"]
    });
}
```

It works with spaces too. If you have **pro_FIP _id_FEC** as a property the same syntax will work. i.e `allFEC[i]["pro_FIP _id_FEC"]`